# FBSDKGraphRequest is not working (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use FBSDKGraphRequest inside the a block of code that executes when the Facebook Login Button was pressed. However, for some reason, this piece of code never executes. What could be the reason. The Button I use is FBSDKLoginButton and it works perfectly. I just one want to retrieve user information such as name and email once login is achieved.

```
[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"email,name"}]
                  startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                      NSLog(@"test");
                      if (!error) {
                          NSLog(@"fetched user:%@  and Email : %@", result,result[@"email"]);
                      }
                  }];
```

Comment: Please add more code you your question, as it stands at the moment it is not clear how you intend to run the mentioned code and it is also not clear if you have implemented the `FBSDKLoginButton` correctly.

Answer (score 3):

I have used custom Facebook login,not with Official Facebook FBSDKLoginButton. Try the below code. Today I integrated Facebook login for my App and came across your question.

```
- (IBAction)FacebookLogin:(id)sender {
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
    [login
     logInWithReadPermissions: @[@"public_profile", @"email", @"user_friends"]
     fromViewController:self
     handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
         if (error) {
             NSLog(@"Process error");
         } else if (result.isCancelled) {
             NSLog(@"Cancelled");
         } else {
             NSLog(@"Logged in");

             [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"email,name"}]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 NSLog(@"fetched user:%@  and Email : %@", result,result[@"email"]);
             }
         }];
         }
     }];
}
```

Comment: Working perfect

Answer (score 2):

Default parameters are id and name, to find email if a user made it public info append email in url field and also can append needed permissions like birthday,etc

```
if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
        [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me?fields=id,name,email" parameters:nil]
         startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
             }
         }];
    }
```

result consists of user name , mail and id.

Then to analyse the profile information, following code,

```
[FBSDKProfile loadCurrentProfileWithCompletion:
     ^(FBSDKProfile *profile, NSError *error) {
         if (profile) {
             NSLog(@"Hello, %@!", profile);
         }
     }];
```

profile consists of userID,firstName,middleName,lastName,name,linkURL,refreshDate